# When does an Devops Organisation security group inherited to the Devops project?

Tags: azure-devops

When i go into my project in Devops, under the pipelines->Manage Security, i can see several Organization security groups, mainly Project Collection "insert role".

I am wondering when a Security group is inherited from the organization to the project?

Because i did create a new Administrator Security group at the Organization level, with no service account access levels, as Microsoft recommends. But when i go to my project, i cannot see my new group having access to my pipelines.

So how does a new group at the organization level get access to a project?

If it is just that they do get access, but it doesn't show, then why does the Project Collection groups show and nothing else?

If it is just that the Default Collection groups that get access, then what is the point of new Security groups?

Detailed list of permissions i set to allow is:

Sure. As i said it has everything enabled, except the service account stuff. Detailed list of everything that is allowed is:

- Alter trace settings
- Create new projects
- Delete team project
- Edit instance-level information
- View instance-level information
- Administer process permissions
- Create process
- Delete field from organization
- Delete process
- Edit process
- Administer shelved changes
- Administer workspaces
- Create a workspace
- Administer build resource permissions
- Manage build resources
- Manage pipeline policies
- Use build resources
- View build resources
- Manage test controllers
- Delete audit streams
- Manage audit streams
- View audit log
- Manage enterprise policies

Again, all i wanted was an admin account without the Service Account accesses.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the Security Group permissions within your newly created Organization-level groups? And was your intent to create a separate organization-level security group that had different permissions from that of the "Project Administrators" group?

Comment: Sure, i edited the main issue. But it is basically allow on everything except for the settings inside of the Service Account settings.

And yes, i wanted to create an administrator collection account without Service account privileges. But i am curious in general about why some organization level accounts are inherited and some are not. Is it just because they are pre created, is it because they have collection in their name, or something else?

Comment: It did answer the first part, but i am still curious about how to manually add an organization level group to a project. So i would like to keep it open just a tiny bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there really aren't any automatically inherited permissions when you create permission groups at the organization-level within Azure DevOps. By default, you have to manually your Organization-Level group to Project-Groups to delegate access, or create a **Group Rule** that will automatically assign access to projects.

In your case, it sounds like a **group rule** will be the best option. Using one will enable you to automatically delegate project access to users within the group. However, there are some limitations to using them.

To create a group rule:

1. Go to your Organization Settings page
2. Head to the **Users** page
3. Click on the **Group Rules** tab
4. Click **Add Group Rule**
5. Select all projects
6. Select **Project Administrator** in the **Azure DevOps Groups** field (This group is close to the settings you're looking to apply to users)

[image: Azure DevOps - Add Group Rule]

7. Click **Save**

I mentioned above that this method has limitations. The primary limitation is that you can only choose from the out-of-the-box security groups when delegating access automatically.  You'll need to take further steps if you want to restrict permissions down from what is included in the **Project Administrator** group the example able uses, you'll have to manually add your custom organization-level group to a project-level group that has those permissions set to **Deny.**

However, in your list of permissions above, you've included all project-level permissions, so I believe this method should work for you.

Here is Microsoft's documentation on using **Group Rules:**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/assign-access-levels-by-group-membership?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This gave me a lot of information, and i will look into it. Out of curiosity, the first comment, "By default, you have to manually [add] your Organization-Level group to Project-Groups to delegate access,", can you elaborate on how i do that? Because that was what i thought i had to do first, but i couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: And another follow up, does that mean that the Project Collection [X] groups are automatically inherited? Because i can see Project Collection Administrator, Build Administrators, Build Service Accounts and Test Service Accounts inherited in my project, but i can't understand why, as they are not in the Group rule view.

Comment: To answer you're first question; In the case of manually adding permissions per-project, you'll need to head into the permissions of each individual project and add your Organization-Level group to the a group that delegates access to resources within the project. With regard to your second question, the "Project Collection [X]" groups have global permissions delegated in a manner that's similar to how Group Rules behave but are not visible to end users.